# Coding bat beginner recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I am unable to find the logic for recursion in the problem mentioned below.
Given a non-negative int n, return the count of the occurrences of 7 as a digit

Eg. Count7(777)=3

Eg. Count7(123)=0

Eg. Count7(171)=1

Here is the logic that i applied

count number of 7 in ones place + count no of 7 in all the other place.

eg 13767

count number of 7 in (1)+ count number off 7 in (3767),just like factorial program where 5!=5*4!

```
count7(n)
{
    if (n==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n==7) { 
        return 1; 
    }
    if (n!=7) {
        return 0;
    }
    return count7(n%10)+count7(n/10)
}
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated .

Comment: I expected this `Count7(171)=0` to be `1` as there *is* a `7`

Comment: BTW: `count7(n)` is wrong, it should be `int count7(n)`. And please format your code correctly, just like they do in your C textbook.

Comment: `n` is either `7` or it isn't, so your last line will never execute.

Comment: `int count7(int n){
 if(!n)
  return 0;
 return (n % 10 == 7) + count7(n/10);
}`

Comment: Your code never reaches the recursion — for any value `n`, the value is either 0 or 7 or not 7, so the recursive code is never executed.

Comment: say if n=5 which is not equal to 7 it will result in termination of program, Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
if (n==7) return 1;
```

followed by

```
if (n!=7) return 0;
```

As `n` is either 7 or not 7, everything that comes after will never be called. Instead you probably want

```
if (n<10) return 0;
```

as you want to call the recursion for numbers with more than 1 digit, and break here if you reached the last digit.

BTW, you could also remove the `if (n==0)` part, as this is also covered by the `n<10`.

Comment: You might also consider the case of `n < 0`, but your point about every value being 0 or 7 or not 7 is valid — the OP's code never recurses.

Answer (score 0):

The base case checks if there is just a single digit and if it is a `7` or not. Then, we recursively add the number of `7`s in the remaining digits to whatever was found before (`rem == 7 ? 1 : 0`). This is just another bare-bones program. I am sure you can pick up from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count7(int i)
{
    int rem = i % 10;  // remainder
    int quo = i / 10;  // quotient

    if (rem == i) {    // base case - check for a single digit.
        if (rem == 7)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    } else {
        return (rem == 7 ? 1 : 0) + count7(quo);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 12;
    printf("%d\n", count7(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is completely functional.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("%d\n",count7(717));
}
int count7(int n)
{
if(n==7)
    return 1;
else if(n<10)
    return 0;
else
    return count7(n%10)+count7(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems that I found in your code,

The `critical problem` is that you check if `n!=7` and befor you check if `n==7`

that combination will equal to Ask the condition `if() {} else {}` that mean that in this case
you will not get to the next line - `return count7(n%10)+count7(n/10)` Never!!!!

Another thing that I saw is that you call at the return to `count7` with the remainder of the number, it will work, but if you need to do a simple operation (check only if the remainder ==7 ) so my advice is to use to `? :` condition and not to jump to function if you don't need.

My Code to your problem:

```
int count7(int n)
{
    return n==0 ? 0 : (n==7 ? 1 : count7(n/10) + (n%10 == 7 ? 1 : 0) );
}
```

And another code more readably (do the same work) :

```
int count7(int curNum)
{
    int curModNum=n%10;
    int curDivNum=n/10;
    if (currentNum==EMPTY_NUM) {
        return EMPTY_NUM;
    }
    if (curNum==LUCKY_NUM) { 
        return ADD_ONE; 
    }
    return count7(curDivNum) + (curModNum == LUCKY_NUM ? ADD_ONE : EMPTY_NUM); 
}
```

Comment: yeah got it ...thanks for clearing . Is there any way i can become good at recursion.

Comment: The best way is practice, and use it only when you need :)

Comment: So the problem was with the base case, not the recursive function